# Java - for loop cycling through string array

Tags: android, arrays, string, for-loop

So I'm new to programming. I have a string array named values that has about 150 strings in it. Instead of using a ton of if statements I wan't to to use a for loop that each time it cycles through the loop increments to the next element in the array. I'm sure it's a super simple fix but I just can't solve it. Thanks for any advice!

```
routeListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,     int position, long id) {

                    String route = values[position];

                    int i;
                    for (i=0; i < values.length;i++) {

                        if (route.equals(values[0])) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), RouteDetails.class);
                            intent.putExtra("route", routeDetail[0]);
                            startActivity(intent);
                      }
                    values++;
                    }
                    /*if (route.equals(values[0])) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), RouteDetails.class);
                        intent.putExtra("route", routeDetail[1]);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                    if (route.equals("Main Wall")) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), RouteDetails.class);
                        intent.putExtra("route", "Map of Main Wall");
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                    if (route.equals("1. Shark Bait - 5.9")) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,     RouteDetails.class);
                        intent.putExtra("route", "Shark Bait");
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
*/
                }
```

Comment: Is this code compilable? `values` is a `String[]`, how can it be incremented using `values++`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of the loop, replace the hard coded 0's with "i". This will allow your code to be ran for each iteration of the loop. For example, the i will be replaced with 0, then 1, then 2, etc.

```
for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {

 if (route.equals(values[i])) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), RouteDetails.class);
    intent.putExtra("route", routeDetail[i]);
    startActivity(intent);
 }
}
```

Also, there is no need to add a counter for values at the end, since it is handled by the i++ in the for loop. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use switches...if you need both int and string comparisons you can use two switches to do that.

```
    String route = values[position];

    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RouteDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("route", routeDetail[0]);
            startActivity(intent);
            return;
        case 1:
            // Do stuff
            return;
    }

    switch(route) {
        case "Main Wall":
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RouteDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("route", "Map of Main Wall");
            startActivity(intent);
            return;

        case "Shark Bait":
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RouteDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("route", "Shark Bait");
            startActivity(intent);
            return;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. So there's no way to not have to use like 150 if statements or switches?